# Problemas con Variables de Sesión - MAGENTO 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Normalmente al crear una cuenta para un dominio en CPANEL, el caché de la plataforma queda se guarda en /home/nombre_de_cuenta/public_html/var/session, sin embargo me está ocurriendo que por algún motivo los archivos temporales de la plataforma se están creando en un directorio llamado MAGENTO ubicado en la raiz del server, específicamente en /tmp/magento/var/session.

De verdad no se que pasa, al revisar en /home/nombre_de_cuenta/public_html/var/session noto que no se genera ningún archivos de sesión.

Que puede estar pasando?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo siento, pero mi espanol no esta tan bueno. Por eso mi respuesta en ingles :-)
It could be a problem with the permissions of the directory var/session within web directory (should be 777). Please check them.